# Passing values to array indexes in Python

Tags: python

Is there any way to assign values to keys in array in Python?

Example in PHP:

```
$inputArr = array(
                'vertex'=>values[0],
                'visited'=>values[1],
                'letter' => $values[2]
                )
```

This is the way i tried to do in Python:

```
file_name = input('Enter a file name: ')
f = open(file_name, 'r')
data = f.readlines() //Read the lines
for line in data: 
      values = line.split(' ') Split line following the spaces
      inputArr = array(
                'vertex'=>values[0], //Pass each value to a key in that array
                'visited'=>values[1],
                'letter' => $values[2]
                )
      print (inputArr)
```

Comment: You have an error on your 'letter' line -> 'letter' => $values[2].. also, arrays in python are dicts. so try using a dictionary

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use [`dict`s](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict):

```
array = {
    'vertex': values[0],
    'visited': values[1],
    'letter': values[2],
}
# access via array['vertex']
```

Note however that this does **not** preserve the order. Iterating over the dictionary can produce an arbitrary order. There is an [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) class in recent versions of python, however keep in mind that it takes more than twice as much memory as a plain `dict`.

If your array is fixed, and only has those 3 elements, it might be better to use a [`namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

```
from collections import namedtuple

NamedSeq = namedtuple('NamedSeq', ('vertex', 'visited', 'letter'))

array = NamedSeq(values[0], values[1], values[2])
#or
array = NamedSeq(vertex=values[0], letter=values[2], visited=values[1])
```

This preserves the order and you can access `vertex` via `array.vertex` etc.
Or you can access the data using `array[0]` for the value of `vertex`, `array[1]` for the `visited` etc.

Note that however that `namedtuple`s are *immutable*, i.e. you cannot modify them.

Answer (score 1):

@Bakuriu's answer is correct

you can also do something like this:

```
for line in data: 
    vertex, visited, letter = line.split() # space is default
    print vertex, visited, letter
```